# GNU gcc/g++ compiler version on solaris for supporting C++11/14

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gdb, g++

I need to know the GNU gcc/g++ version alongwith gmake, gdb and other GNU build tools for upgrading to C++11 first and then to C++14. Please suggest which stable version to look at/download? I will be requiring the compiler/build suite for solaris 32-bit. Please suggest.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x). If you scroll further down you'll see the implementation status for C++14.

Answer (score 1):

For C++11, version 4.8.1 or later: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html.

For C++14, version 5 or later: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html.